# Simple frameworks for drawing a generated maze in C++

Tags: c++, maze, kruskals-algorithm

I generate a maze using a randomized version of Kruskal's. The program logic for generating the maze is not an issue for me.I am having trouble figuring out how I would actually go about physically displaying the maze drawing.

To my understanding, the initial maze would start as a H by W grid, where each cell has all of its "borders"/walls in place. My only experience with C++ drawing is simply printing chars in the terminal, to represent different figures. However, it doesn't seem suited for more complex drawings like a cell of a certain width and height surrounded by 4 much thinner black lines. I suppose I could surround each cell character with 8 wall characters, but that seems quite cumbersome and not very elegant (walls would look bulky/ not thin).

I have seen some awesome screenshots on SO that people have taken of their generated maze, where they were able to draw the thin walls surrounded the cells with ease. I have never used a graphing/drawing library in C++ and after a few hours of search I am still quite lost.

For those algorithmic fanatics out there, what are the simplest frameworks to draw simple grids/mazes in C++?

Comment: The reason you have been downvoted is probably that asking for the best or easiest framework is an opinion based question and does not strictly belong on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @turoni That is most likely it, my original post was actually twice as long and a bit too vague, so I cut it down and edited a bunch. With that said, for my future post I will do my best to stay away from anything too open-ended or opinion based. Thank you for the suggestion mate!

Comment: This question might be better phrased to ask something a little more factual than opinion based such as "Which libraries allow you to draw and display images to the screen with tutorials showing you how?"

Comment: I think there would still be people that have problems with such a question but it'd at least not be opinion based.

Comment: fyi how to have more fun with Kruskal generation: https://mtimmerm.github.io/webStuff/maze.html

Answer (score 2):

Without a specific library for displaying images you won't be able to actually show your image. [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) has a fantastic range of tools for generating, editing and displaying images. There are a huge amount of [tutorials](https://docs.opencv.org/4.x/d9/df8/tutorial_root.html) from step by step installation for your system to doing anything you may wish to do with OpenCV.

A simple enough method regardless of the libraries you use might be to

1. Create an image in memory with *n* pixels per unit in your grid. So your image would be (*n* * H) x (*n* * W) pixels large
2. Set all the pixels to be a single colour
3. Loop over every unit in your grid which is a path and draw a square of a second colour on your image from (*n**W, *n**H) to (*n**[W+1], *n**[H+1])
4. Draw the image to your output object

What you will end up with is a 2-tone image with walls the background colour and the path the foreground colour.

Unfortunately I cannot be any more specific without code examples or you picking the libraries you would like to use. OpenCV is widelyu used and so widely supported, so I recommend that.

Comment: OpenCV looks great, plenty of tutorials too! Thank you for the suggestion and your method was very helpful.

Comment: If it helped please remember to upvote :)

Comment: I actually did up vote but I'm guessing since i was below 15 reputation points maybe it didn't work? Anyway here you go mate!